# Session in AJAX php file is not updating

Tags: php, ajax, session, updating

I am facing a problem with updating the value of my SESSION named "subs". When I click to .userLink, a profile of specific user should show. That works - all profile informations are changing according to link I am clicking on. Even my session get the right value. But just once. When I click to another user link, profile information is changed (first name, last name, ...) but the value of my session stay same till I delete cookies. Then I am able to get the right value once again.

I am totally frustrated. I cannot find a mistake. 
AJAX is working correctly, all files have session_start() on top.

Can somebody help me, please?

JAVASCRIPT (AJAX CALL)

```
$(".userLink").click(function() {
        var user = $(this).html();
        var dataString = 'uzivatel='+ user;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "includes/showProfile.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(result){
            $("#otherProfile").toggle();

            $("#nameSection h2").html(result[1]);
            $("#nameSection h1").html(result[2]);
            $("#Pbirthdate").html(result[3]);
            $("#Pgender").html(result[4]);
            $("#description").html(result[5]);
          }
        });

      });
```

showProfile.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'connect.php';

$profileOwner = $_POST['uzivatel'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$profileOwner'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $_SESSION["subs"] = $row["userID"];
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $lastname = $row["surname"];
    $birth = $row["birthdate"];
    $birth = date( "j.n.Y", strtotime($birth));
    if($row["gender"] == "male"){
      $gender = "MUŽ";
    } else{
      $gender = "ŽENA";
    }
  }
}

$file="../profiles/".$ID."/description.txt";
$imageFile="profiles/".$ID."/profileImage.jpg";

if(file_exists($file)){
   $description = file_get_contents($file);
}

$array = array($ID,$firstname,$lastname,$birth,$gender,$description);
echo json_encode($array);


$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You cannot change a session in a remote page and expect the session to be set in your current page. Changing session information requires page reloads.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, I did not realize that. Can you recommend me the best way to get value from AJAX file to the main php file if I need to work with it using PHP? When I use echo to get the value it is a JS variable and it is a little difficult to work with it using PHP then.

Comment: If you need to work with a variable using PHP you have to send the variable information, via AJAX, to the PHP processing script. PHP can then return it as a JavaScript variable. Or you can force a page reload.

Comment: Oh my god. How easy... Why I need somebody to "kick" me sometimes... :-D Thank you very much. You are my kicker for today. :-D

Comment: Glad to have kicked! ;-)